# What does "RunCommand acCmdCompatCheckDatabase" do?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm just curious how or when or why I would use this command:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCompatCheckDatabase
```

Comment: That would be `acCmdCompactDatabase`. @HelO'Ween

Comment: @Andre, you're correct, ofc. I deleted my wrong comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as the menu command

```
File -> Save & Publish -> Publish to Access Services -> Run Compatibility Checker
```

(in Access 2010, I don't have a newer version here to check how it's called there.)

See [Build an Access database to share on the Web](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/build-an-access-database-to-share-on-the-web-cca08e35-8e51-45ce-9269-8942b0deab26)

Comment: Correct - the command checks if the database can be published as a web application. Those 2010 web applications allow VBA and VBA client forms to be published (but not run), so even VBA and  non web forms will in fact pass the compatibility check.